# Массив, который возвращает метод Split нужно засунуть в еще один массив

Tags: c#, массивы, split

Split всегда возвращает 3 элемента.Поэтому j<3.

```
int count = 8;
string[] coordinates = new string[count];
string[][] splitedCoordinates = new string[count][];
for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Length; ++i)
{

    splitedCoordinates[i] = new string[3];
    for(int j=0,j<3)
    {
        splitedCoordinates[i][j] = coordinates[i].Split(' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: Что этот код должен делать? Что с ним не так?

Comment: Здесь есть ступенчатый массив. Мне в этот массив нужно внести массив , который возвращает метод Split. Однако когда я пытаюсь это сделать у меня происходит ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Если просто нужно результат `coordinates[i].Split(' ');` присвоить строке в `splitedCoordinates`, то можно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Length; ++i)
{
    splitedCoordinates[i] = coordinates[i].Split(' ');
}
```

Ошибка возникает видимо по тому, что код пытается присвоить массив элементу типа `string`. Еще цикл for какой-то странный.

Ну и да, можно для этого использовать Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var splitedCoordinates = coordinates.Select(c => c.Split(' ')).ToArray();
```